# How to use proxies correctly?

Tags: http, go, request

I send a request and bypass cloudflare using the library. I want to use a proxy, but if I add a proxy as usual, the program crashes.

```
headers := map[string]string{
    "Accept":     "*/*",
    "User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
}
proxyStr := "http://101.68.61.82:8085"
proxyURL, _ := url.Parse(proxyStr)
transport := &http.Transport{
    Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyURL),
}
client := http.Client{Timeout: 5 * time.Second, Transport: transport}
client.Transport = cloudflarebp.AddCloudFlareByPass(client.Transport)
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://api.openproxy.space/lists/http", nil) 
for k, v := range headers {
    req.Header.Set(k, v)
}
resp, _ := client.Do(req)
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
fmt.Println(string(body))
```

error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x40 pc=0x38f96d]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.requesti()
     C:/Users/user/Desktop/go/parser/test.go:33 +0x40d
main.main()
    C:/Users/user/Desktop/go/parser/test.go:13 +0x17
exit status 2
```

How do I add a proxy correctly? If I remove the addition of the proxy, everything works perfectly

33 line: defer resp.Body.Close()
13 line: func call

Comment: What is on line 13 of test.go? Also, don't ignore the errors.

Comment: Where is test.go:33 in the posted code?

Comment: 33 line: defer resp.Body.Close()

Comment: line 13 is func call

Comment: What is the error returned from `client.Do(req)`?  The program in the question ignores that error.

Comment: @Cerise Limón error: Get "https://api.openproxy.space/lists/http": Bad Request. I think if it was just a proxy error, it would just give a bad request without a fatal error

Comment: The program panics because the response returned from `client.Do(req)` is nil.  Fix the reported error.

Comment: @Cerise Limón I fixed it and the request is sent, but now cloudflare is not bypassed) The developer of the cloudflare bypass library said this: Using the http.DefaultTransport will currently still fail, nil or empty &http.Transport works. Didn't have the time to check what exactly is different causing the CloudFlare validation to fail though.

Comment: Is there any other way to add a proxy to the request? I tried to find it, but I couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution using this library. Use other ways.